# Passwords saved from my browser are saved in my PC?

Tags: security, passwords

I want to ask, are the passwords that my browser(like Chrome and Firefox) ask if i want to save are saved in some file in my PC ?

If yes is this file encrypted and where can i find it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [Chrome](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/look-up-or-back-up-google-chrome-saved-passwords/), the file will be at `C:\Users\[yourusername]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Login Data`.

For [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data), your passwords are stored in the key3.db and logins.json files (under `C:\Users\[yourusername]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\`)

The files will be encrypted of course.

Comment: So Chrome saves passwords data in my PC and Firefox don't ? Or this db or login.json file is in my PC ?

Comment: Firefox also stores encrypted passwords. See my edit.

Comment: I guess the first comment, which stated that they are not stored locally was wrong, because it was deleted. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: http://securityxploded.com/chromepassworddecryptor.php claims to be capable of decrypting this file, and the browser can too of course, so I dont quitesee the point of the extra encryption. Well at least the OS wont index it.